# How can I quit an in-progress git merge operation in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, merge

I'm working on a project in VS code. I made changes, pulled from GitHub and got merge conflicts. I don't know what i did but my merge conflict screen now looks like this (it's highlighting the file as one big merge conflict?). I don't want to delete any of my progress in this file. Is there a way to "reset" (quit) the merge so I can try merging again?

[image]

Comment: you have a merge conflict, any way you want to incorporate the new stuff you have to resolve the conflict, best to do it now, use VSC ar merge conflict tool or any other 3 way merge tool, or do it by editing the file with a conflict unaware editor, search for the conflict markers, use `git status` to see what git expects you to do

Comment: And to emphasize: you really want to use a *proper* 3-way merge tool (which sort of despite its name has *four* windows/panes). [KDiff3](https://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) is such tool and you can use [my script](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) to launch it with the correct arguments. (Despite Microsoft's claims, what they have is not a proper 3-way merge tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `Git: Merge Abort` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette). Its command ID is `git.mergeAbort`. The command pretty much just does [`git merge --abort`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---abort).